# How to obtain the number of dice rolls it takes to roll a certain number?

Tags: java

Directions: Keep "rolling the dice" until a total of seven is reached, and keep track of how many rolls it takes to reach the seven.  Print out the number of rolls for each trial.

After every trial, the number of rolls remains the same, and I don't know why.

```
    import java.util.*;
  public class GeometricDistribution {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
    int input = 0;
    //loop if the user doesn't enter an actual integer
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer value, please.");
      keyboard.nextLine();  //remove everything the user input 
    }
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (input <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a POSITIVE integer.");
      input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int numRolls = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
      while ((sum) != 7) {
        numRolls++;
        int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        sum = die1 + die2;
      }
      System.out.println("You rolled a 7 on roll #" + numRolls);
    }           
  }
}
```

EDIT: Here's what my code looks like now:

```
    int sum;
int numRolls = 0;
int sumRolls = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
  sum = 0; 
  while ((sum) != 7) {
    numRolls++;
    int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    sum = die1 + die2;
  }
  System.out.println("You rolled a 7 on roll #" + numRolls);
  sumRolls += numRolls;
}
System.out.println("Average number of rolls to get a 7: " + (sumRolls/input));
```

Does that look right?

EDIT:

Here's the final code I submitted to my professor for this program. The explicit, complete directions are as follows:

> Write a program to run a simple probability experiment a total of N
>   trials (where N is a positive integer input from the user).  In each
>   trial of the experiment, simulate the rolling of two six-sided dice
>   using random numbers and compute the total.  Keep "rolling the dice"
>   until a total of seven is reached, and keep track of how many rolls it
>   takes to reach the seven.  Print out the number of rolls for each
>   trial.  For example, in the first trial it might take five rolls
>   before a seven is seen (the seven appears on the fifth roll) and on
>   the second trial it might take eight rolls until a seven and so on. 
>   At the end of the program print out the average number of rolls it
>   took to get a seven over the N trials. notes:
>   + your program should check that the user's input for N is a positive integer.  it should re-prompt the user until they enter a positive
>   integer if they enter 0 or a negative number.  (if the user enters a
>   non-integer, you can let the program crash)
>   + the simplest way will probably use a while-loop for each trial nested inside a for-loop that counts the total number of trials up to
>   N
>   + you will need to keep track of the sum of the number of rolls it took from each trial to be able to compute the average after all the
>   trials have finished
>   + this program simulates a geometric probability distribution...as N increases the average number of trials to reach a 7 should approach 6
>   (since there is a 1/6 chance of rolling a 7)

My answer:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HW9 {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
    int input = 0;
    //loop if the user doesn't enter an actual integer
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer value, please.");
      keyboard.nextLine();  //remove everything the user input 
    }
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (input <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a POSITIVE integer.");
      input = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    int sumRolls = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
      int sum = 0;
      int numRolls = 0;
      while ((sum) != 7) {
        int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        sum = die1 + die2;
        numRolls++;
      }
      System.out.println("You rolled a 7 on roll #" + numRolls);
      sumRolls += numRolls;
    }
    System.out.println("Average number of rolls to get a 7: " + (sumRolls/input));
  }
}
```

Please let me know your thoughts about the above code in terms of its efficiency and elegance.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You should learn "do while", like "do { numRolls++; die1 = ...;sum = die1+die2;}while(sum != 7);"

Comment: Hey Mikkel, thank you for your insight. Can you take a look at the latest edit and let me know your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
  sum = 0; // add this
  while ((sum) != 7) {
    numRolls++;
    int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    sum = die1 + die2;
  }
  System.out.println("You rolled a 7 on roll #" + numRolls);
}
```

You need to restart sum every for iteration

Comment: Check out the edit. Something about resetting the sum yields the wrong values for the average number of rolls needed to get a 7 calculation. It should be approaching 6 with an increasing amount of trials.

Answer (score 0):

you need a `printf` for every iteration in your loop

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
      while ((sum) != 7) {
        numRolls++;
        int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        sum = die1 + die2;
        System.out.printf("You rolled a %d on roll #" + numRolls + "\n", sum);
      }

    }
```

Comment: Haven't learned the printf method yet... will look into it on the API. Thank you for your input, Hamid.

Comment: @tharooj, so u can simply replace `printf` with this one `System.out.println("You rolled a " + sum + "on roll #" + numRolls);`

Answer (score 0):

You will evaluate sum != 7 one less time by:

```
do {
  numRolls++;
  int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
  int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
  sum = die1 + die2;
} while ((sum) != 7);
```

and by calculating sum just before the evaluation gives the compiler a better chance of not using any memory for sum. Similar having sum right after die2 means not using memory for die2 either. So the last 3 lines gives a better chance of the most optimized resulting code.

A more special optimizing would be:

```
do {
  ++numRolls;
  twodices = (int)(Math.random()*36; // Throws 2 dices at the same time
} while (twodices < 6); // 0 - 5 represents the 6 different throws giving 7.
```